# Assign ID to each two columns imported from Excel file

Tags: c#, dictionary

[image]I trying to import data from excel and for each two connected column i store the data into two dimensional list except the last column which will be in a 1D list. i wanna assign an id for each set of data the code get to be able to build a dictionary later for them.

that means for the first( valLat and valLng together ) i want to assign id = 1 and so on for each List

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
                {
                    var pickLocation = new PickLocation();
                    var valLat = ((Excel.Range)wks.Cells[i, PickLocation.ColumnLat]).Value;
                    var valLng = ((Excel.Range)wks.Cells[i, PickLocation.ColumnLng]).Value;


                    if (!(valLat == null) & !(valLng == null))
                    {
                        pickLocation.Lat = Convert.ToDouble(valLat);
                        pickLocation.Lng = Convert.ToDouble(valLng);
                        ListPickLocations.Add(pickLocation);
                    }

                    var setLocation = new SetLocation();
                    valLat = ((Excel.Range)wks.Cells[i, SetLocation.ColumnLat]).Value;
                    valLng = ((Excel.Range)wks.Cells[i, SetLocation.ColumnLng]).Value;

                    if (!(valLat == null) & !(valLng == null))
                    {
                        setLocation.Lat = Convert.ToDouble(valLat); ;
                        setLocation.Lng = Convert.ToDouble(valLng);
                        ListSetlocations.Add(setLocation);
                    }

                    var craneLocation = new CraneLocation();
                    valLat = ((Excel.Range)wks.Cells[i, CraneLocation.ColumnLat]).Value;
                    valLng = ((Excel.Range)wks.Cells[i, CraneLocation.ColumnLng]).Value;

                    if (!(valLat == null) & !(valLng == null))
                    {
                        craneLocation.Lat = Convert.ToDouble(valLat); ;
                        craneLocation.Lng = Convert.ToDouble(valLng);
                        ListCranelocations.Add(craneLocation);
                    }

                    var weight = ((Excel.Range)wks.Cells[i, 10]).Value;

                    if (!(weight == null))
                    {
                        Weights.Add(Convert.ToDouble(weight));
                    }

                    var clearance = ((Excel.Range)wks.Cells[2, 12]).Value;

                    if (!(clearance == null))
                    {
                        Clearance = clearance;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}

    public class PickLocation
{

    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }


    public static int ColumnLat { get; } = 4;
    public static int ColumnLng { get; } = 5;
}
public class CraneLocation
{

    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }

    public static int ColumnLat { get; } = 1;
    public static int ColumnLng { get; } = 2;
}
public class SetLocation
{

    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }

    public static int ColumnLat { get; } = 7;
    public static int ColumnLng { get; } = 8;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought you are adding them to  `ListPickLocations`. Do you want to turn that to a dictionary?

Comment: yea i want to change them all into dictionaries